# Mostrar select dependiente de input

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario donde quiero que al digitar un numero de item en un input, me aparezca en un select la descripción perteneciente a ese item.

El item y la descripción son de una tabla en MySQL.

He estado investigando y solo veo soluciones a la inversa.

---

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('ITEM').onchange = function(){
        var c = document.getElementById('ITEM').value;
        document.getElementById('DESCRIPCION').innerHTML = c;
        }
    }
</script>

<form>
<tr>
    <td width="100" align="right"><font face="arial" size="-1"><b>ITEM</b></font></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ITEM" id="ITEM" style="width:100px;" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $fila['ITEM']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3"><textarea name="DESCRIPCION" id="DESCRIPCION" cols="45" rows="3" style="width:350px;" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['DESCRIPCION']; ?></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="100" align="right"><font face="arial" size="-1"><b>DESCRIPCION</b></font></td>
  </tr>


<form>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el codigo que llevas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que la descripción la muestres en un textarea, el select se usa para que el usuario pueda escoger entre varias opciones.

Este script te va a ayudar a comprender, se usa JQuery para crear un evento change sobre el input, el evento obtiene la descripcion de acuerdo al número ingresado y lo carga en el textarea.

Por supuesto es un ejemplo básico, hay que implementar validaciones.

Saludos,

```js
var data = [{
  numero: 1,
  descripcion: "uno"
}];

$("#txtNumero").change(function () {
 var value = this.value;
    var descripcion = data.filter(function (record) {
  return (record.numero == value);
 });
    
    $("#tarDescripcion").val(descripcion[0].descripcion);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="txtNumero" name="txtNumero">
<textarea id="tarDescripcion"></textarea>
```

Comment: Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora: